# Push a VS2019 project to GitHub

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

I'm trying to share after many years of benefiting from others work. I looked and Googled and by all indication the process is relatively easy.

My Issue is that I already had myself set up to push to my Z:drive aka my NAS. It was convenient for keeping my machines synced.

So my question is, can you have multiple push locations in VS2019 Team Explorer, and if not how do I change it? I'm thinking Git Hub is actually more convenient when I travel, even without the sharing.

Answer (score 1):

One of the cool things about Git is the ability to have multiple remotes.

A `remote` is essentially just a server to which you push the code to. This makes it easy to:

(1) Push branches to multiple servers.

(2) Push certrain branches to certain servers.

To see your current repo's remotes, execute:
`git remote -v`

By default, the initial remote after you clone a repo is named 'origin'. This is similar to how the initial branch created when you initialize a repo is 'master'... but Git is very flexible. Just as you can rename your root branch you can also delete that default remote and add a new remote with a different name such as `bitbucket` or `github`.

I should highlight that the "name" for your remote does not have to match url it pushes to... but by naming it more specifically you can help identify to yourself what server you are pushing to.

Example command to add a remote:

`git remote add bph https://github.com/benhorgen/nunit`

The command above would create a new remote named "bph" that pushed to the Git repo "nunit"